# Python3. Декорирование методов внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, декоратор

Есть класс который содержит большое количество методов для работы с API (больше сотни), чтобы не городить для каждого метода одинаковое логирование, хочу обернуть все методы декоратором с логированием результатов выполнения метода.

UPDATE: Класс содержит методы API, но так же в классе есть и служебные методы. Обернуть надо только все методы API.

**main.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("* Test *")

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api = None

    def __test_logging(api_method):

        def func(*args: str, **kwargs):
            resp = api_method(*args, **kwargs)
            if resp:
                logging.info("{} - Success".format(args))
            elif resp is None:
                logging.warning("{} - Not Found".format(args))
            else:
                logging.error("{} - Unreachable".format(args))
            return resp
        return func

    @ __test_logging
    def update_user(self, *method: str, **param: dict):
        resp = None # api.update_user(**param)
        return resp

    @ __test_logging
    def delete_user(self, *method: str, **param: dict):
        resp = False  # api.delete_user(**param)
        return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test = Test()

    user = {"user_id": "u000001"}
    result = test.update_user(*"Update User",  **user)
    print(result)
```

И вроде бы работает, но крайне криво. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать идею.

```
WARNING:root:(<__main__.Test object at 0x039F5310>, 'U', 'p', 'd', 'a', 't', 'e', ' ', 'U', 's', 'e', 'r') - Not Found
```

P.S. Конфигурация `logging` находится в отдельном файле.

Comment: Отдельные буквы выводит как отдельные параметры из-за того, что вы `"Update User"` передаете через звездочку: `result = test.update_user(*"Update User",  **user)`. Вообще, желательно привести пример, какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: @insolor - Да, Вы правы, решением оказалось правильное расставление * и **
Собственно в декораторе необходимо было заменить пару строка на `def func(self, args: str, **kwargs):` и `resp = api_method(self, args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

Советую эту [утилиту](https://pypi.org/project/decorate-all-methods/), более древний подход - написать декоратор для класса, в котором через `inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod)` определять всем методам декоратор. Более детальный пример старых методов [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-to-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for-eac)

Comment: К несчастью методы не совсем подходят, под вечер уже был не так внимателен и допустил не совсем точную формулировку волпроса. В классе есть методы API, а есть, скажем так "служебные методы". Так вот обернуть надо только методы API

Comment: Ну тогда смотритE вторую ссылку, хардкодите методы, которые хотите обернуть и когда перебираете inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod)  - проверяете, что это нужный метод

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант декорирования отдельных методов в классе

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api = None

    def __test_logging(api_method):

        def func(self, args: str, **kwargs): # рабочий вариант
            resp = api_method(self, args, **kwargs) # рабочий вариант
            if resp:
                 print("{} method - Success".format(args))
            else:
                print("{} method - Not Found".format(args))
            return resp
        return func


    @ __test_logging
    def update_user(self, *method: str, **param: dict):
        resp = True # api.update_user(**param)
        return resp
```

Answer (score 0):

Если аргументы в функции api просто передаются "как есть", то перечислять сотню методов, конечно же, незачем, вот, для примера, "апи" над обычным словарем

```
class ApiFacade(object):

    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api

    class ApiWrapper:
        """Прокси-объект стандартной обработки вызовов api """

        def __init__(self, fun):
            self.fun = fun

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print('===>', self.fun.__name__, args, kwargs)
            result = self.fun(*args, **kwargs)
            # Тут у меня стоял вброс исключения при ненулевом коде возврата,
            # поскольку api был в стиле C
            print(self.fun.__name__, '===>', result)
            return result

    def __getattr__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        """Перенаправление "неизвестных" функций с постфиксом _api на
        объект api, можно и просто все неизвестные функции отправить
        на вызов api, но с постфиксом, кажется, понятнее """
        postfix = "_api"
        fn = item[:-len(postfix)]
        if item.endswith(postfix):
            return ApiFacade.ApiWrapper(self.api.__getattribute__(fn))
        raise AttributeError("ApiFacade object has no attribute '%s'" % item)

    def foo(self, s):
        print("foo:", s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = dict(a=1, b=2)
    f = ApiFacade(d)
    f.foo('qq')
    f.get_api('a')
    f.keys_api()
    f.__len___api()
```